# PyQt5: Trying to listen from server but error says client_socket is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-sockets

I am new to PyQt5. I have a chat application in which client should receive a text when he first enters the application. I built the GUI in Qt Designer and connected all the widgets as needed. When I start the client application it throws an error

> msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8") 
>   NameError: name 'client_socket' is not defined

Also the text from the server is not displaying in the client window.

Here is the Client code:

```
import chatRoomUI
import sys
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, socket
from threading import Thread
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class ChatWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
        super(ChatWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = chatRoomUI.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.sendBtn.clicked.connect(self.send)
        self.myMsg = self.ui.msgInput 
        self.msgDisplay = self.ui.msgOutput

def receive():
    """Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
            self.msgDisplay.setText(msg)
        except OSError:  # Possibly client has left the chat.
            break

def send(self):
    """"Handles sending of messages."""
    msg = self.myMsg.toPlainText()
    self.myMsg.setPlainText("")
    client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    self.msgDisplay.setText(msg)
    if msg == "/exit":
        client_socket.close()
        self.destroy()

def on_closing(self):
    """This function is to be called when the window is closed."""
    self.myMsg.setPlainText("/exit")
    Send()


# sockets part
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 33000

BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ChatWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Can I ask, what version of python you are using?

Comment: correct the identification of your code

Comment: @Rob I am using python 3.5